# Как избежать warning

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, xcode

```
-(Fraction *) initWith:(int) n :(int) d
```

При объявлении метода выводит варнинг: 'n' used as the name of the previous parameter, не знаю как задать "n" чтобы этого избежать.

P.S. Не ругайтесь, я еще донышко.

Answer (score 2):

Это потому что вы используете не совсем корректную, хотя и допустимую сигнатуру метода. Попробуйте так:

```
-(Fraction *) initWithN:(int) n andD:(int) d
```

Comment: Блин не заметил, думал у Васи двойное имя.

Comment: Варнинги пропали, спасибо большое за помощь)